# NoClassDefFoundError, jar is present

Tags: android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I am attempting to use the `com.integralblue.HttpResponseCache` compatibility library with my Android application. I have copied its jar file together with its dependency, `com.jakewharton.disklrucache`, into the `libs` folder of my project.

When running the program, any call on `HttpResponseCache` causes the program to fail with a `NoClassDefFoundError` on `com.jakewharton.disklrucache`. Both JARs are present in the libs folder and can be imported. Google search turns up absolutely nothing.

How do I solve a `NoClassDefFoundError` when all required JARs are present?

Comment: Try adding the library in the build path as well.

Comment: Just because they're in the lib folder doesn't necessarily mean they're on the class path, unless you're doing a wildcard import.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse the newer ADT's can be a little difficult requiring you to configure the build path and even specify that these jars should be exported to your android app (included in the apk basically):

Project > Properties > Java Build Path

Under Libraries make sure your jars appear, if they don't try doing and clean and rebuild. They should automatically be added, if you're having to add them yourself (which you can) it'll cause other complications like you'll have to export them as well under "Order and Export".

Then under "Order and Export" make sure "Android Private Libraries" is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the google play services on the SDK manager and it worked.